# Creating a styled component inside a component function

Tags: javascript, react.js

In one of my React components, I want to use `props` when creating a styled-component to determine which tag to use. Specifically I am looking for what's in `props.headingLevel` to decide which heading level to create. E.g. `h1` or `h2`.

All of the styled-components examples show components being created outside of the React component class or function, however I have only got this working by creating the styled-component inside the function when `props` is available. I know you can use `props` *inside* of the styled-component via the `props` passed to the styled-component itself within the React function but at this point it's too late.

So my question is twofold. Is it acceptable to create styled-components inside React components functions? And, is there a better way to manage dynamic tags, e.g. creating a styled-component tag based on context or `props` passed?

Here is my component:

```
// Modules
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// Data
import styleData from '../../../data/styles';

const SupplementaryTitle = styled.span`
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
`

const Title = (props) => {
    const HeadingLevel = props.headingLevel ? props.headingLevel : 'h2';
    const StyledHeading = styled(HeadingLevel)`
        margin: 0;
        font-weight: ${styleData['typography_settings']['title'][props.typographySize]['weight']};
        font-size: ${styleData['typography_settings']['title'][props.typographySize]['size']};
        font-family: ${styleData['typography_settings']['title'][props.typographySize]['font']};
        line-height: ${styleData['typography_settings']['title'][props.typographySize]['line_height']};
    `

    const hasSupplementaryTitle = props.supplementaryTitle;

    if (hasSupplementaryTitle) {
        return (
            <StyledHeading>
                {props.children}
                <SupplementaryTitle>{props.supplementaryTitle}</SupplementaryTitle>
            </StyledHeading>
        )
    }

    return (
        <StyledHeading>{props.children}</StyledHeading>
    )
}

Title.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    headingLevel: PropTypes.string,
    typographySize: PropTypes.oneOf([
        'small', 'medium', 'large'
    ]).isRequired,
    supplementaryTitle: PropTypes.string,
}

export default Title;
```

Comment: If voting this question down, please specify your reasons why so that I can improve the question.

Comment: It's not my DV but this code is incomplete and there isn't really much to review...

Comment: Updated to include full component code rather than snippet. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

You generally should not to nest your components. Though when the component is small enough, like a one-liner, it's fine to do so.

In your specific case, you can make use of [withComponent](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#withcomponent) method to change the tag name of an existing component:

```
const Heading = styled.h2`
    margin: 0;
    ...lots of css...
`;

const Title = (props) => {
    const StyledHeading = Heading.withComponent(props.headingLevel || "h2");
    ...
};
```

You'd still be defining the `StyledHeader` inside another component, but most of the code would live outside.

**Additionally...**

- I noticed these long lines:

  ```
  font-weight: ${styleData['typography_settings']['title'][props.typographySize]['weight']};
  ```

  Looks like this `styleData` is some sort of theme. I suggest you look into  [built-in theming support of styled components](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#theming) before rolling your own.
- The variable `hasSupplementaryTitle` can be eliminated. It's conventional to perform an existence check by just:

  ```
  if (props.supplementaryTitle) {
  ```

Comment: This is great feedback! Thanks. Definitely going to make use of `withComponent` and I don't know why I made the decision to have `hasSupplementaryTitle`. Over explaining myself in the code. I am going to look into theming more to see if it fits what I'm trying to do, `styleData` is basically a big object with all of my style values and the context they apply to, derived from the idea of design tokens.